# grep with sed doing multiple replace

Tags: sed, grep

I am using the below command to replace all instance of `schema_name.table_name` to `hello.schema_name.table_name` in my file

`grep -rIEli '(\"|\s)schema_name\.table_name(\"|\s)' | xargs sed -E -i 's/schema_name.table_name/hello.schema_name.table_name/ig'`

But the output i get is
`hello.hello.schema_name.table_name`

Could someone help me with why this is happening ?

When I try to run just this part of the command, then it works fine, but in combination with grep it does not work.
`'s/schema_name.table_name/hello.schema_name.table_name/ig'`

Comment: Please give us a way to reproduce your problem, something like `printf "schema_name.table_name\n" | sed 's/X/Y/'` and the required output VS the current output (the `grep` doesn't seem to be the problem). Good luck.

Comment: Is it possible that your files are getting picked up twice? The files are being picked up by the grep and supplied to sed (via xargs) which does the replacement in place (directly in file).  From the symptoms it appears that the same replacement is happening twice.

Comment: `sed -i` in a pipeline doesn't make much sense.  `-i` doesn't mean 'case insensitive' ... it means "edit the file in place."

Answer (score 1):

Your code is:

```
grep -rIEli '(\"|\s)schema_name\.table_name(\"|\s)' |
xargs sed -E -i '
    s/schema_name.table_name/hello.schema_name.table_name/ig
'
```

Note that your sed regex is not the same as your grep regex.

Consider:

```
echo "1 2 3 4 5" | grep 2 | sed 's/3/---/g'
```

which outputs:

```
1 2 --- 4 5
```

Would you expect sed to replace the `2`?

---

We would have to see actual input/code/output to say more.

What you appear to be saying ("it works fine") is that something like:

```
echo "1 2 3 4 5" | sed 's/3/---/g'
```

returns:

```
1 --- 3 4 5
```

which seems rather unbelievable.

Ignoring that you have not escaped the `.` in sed, your grep and sed regex are actually of the form:

```
grep -l 'ABA' | xargs sed 's/B/C/g'
```

I would expect sed to replace **all** the grep matches as well as making some additional (unwanted) changes.